# Run SBT command on module

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sub-project that's aggregated under some root project.
Sub project defines [`commands`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html) e.g:

```
lazy val `sub` = project
  ...
 .settings(
    commands ++= Seq(Command.args("abc", ""){(state,args) =>
          ??? //edited
    })
  )
```

Normally when command is defined as top-most in the sbt I just run:

```
sbt> abc
```

However I'm unable to do this when defined on module:

```
sbt> sub/abc
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: abc (similar: watch, doc)
[error] sub/abc
[error]             ^
```

How to run `abc` at the `sub` level?

Comment: You'd need to register your command to [State](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Build-State.html) if you want to run it the way you suggested. Otherwise, you have to switch project in order to run the command: *sbt "project sub" abc*